# Can you show youtube videos on your website without embedding them?

Tags: html

I have my site so that people can upload urls of the videos to the database and with php it should in theory display said video. I don't want to use the embed tag because that doesn't work from mobile device. Is there a way to use the videos with just the url's?

```html
<video controls>
  <source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3FPvI5p8Zo" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I expect the video to show, but the actual result is it not working.

Comment: If you take a look at the source of `https://www.youtube.com/embed/S3FPvI5p8Zo` you will notice that it's a HTML page, not an MP4 video!

Comment: Sorry I added the wrong link, but still the same problem. Are you saying because it's a web page and not just the video its not going to play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is by using a cover photo and a link to youtube.com

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3FPvI5p8Zo">
    <img src="images/cover-image.jpg">
</a>
```

Another is to use jquery and fancybox (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/) and create a pop up:

HTML:

```
<a id="fancybox-vid"></a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#fancybox-vid').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.fancybox({
        href: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/S3FPvI5p8Zo?autoplay=1", 
        type: "iframe",
        padding: 0,
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
              locked: false
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides embed tag, there are two more ways to upload a video in HTML:
 1. object tag
 2. iframe tag
Do you try it out?

```
<object width="425" height="344" data="https://www.youtube.com/embed/F9Bo89m2f6g"></object>
<iframe  width="425" height="344" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/F9Bo89m2f6g" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

These urls are links to a page which hosts the youtube video, not a direct link to the media content itself. It's my understanding that the video controls attribute would be for content you either host yourself or remote content that is a direct link, since you're instructing the browser to play the content on your page directly from that source. I don't think there is a way to do what you're trying to do without use of an iframe. Unless you'd like your website to try to download the media from youtube, name it, store it, and present it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is by using  Iframe tag and a link to youtube.com

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/S3FPvI5p8Zo" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```